# angular ng-repeat accessing next item

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'd like to reference the next element is this possible within the ng-repeat directive ?

```
 <li ng-repeat="row in rows">
      if {{row.someValue}} === {{row+1.someValue}}
      //Is it poss to check if the following row so I can do some kind of conditional comparison ?
 </li>
```

Thanks
W

Comment: `{{ row.someValue === rows[$index+1].someValue ? 'do something' : 'something else'}}`

Comment: Why is it now Im thinking of a pumpkin spiced latte : ?

Answer (score 1):

As @PSL said - you just need to get the next index in the array you are looping:

```
 <li ng-repeat="row in rows">
          {{rows[$index+1]}} // this will give you the next row's data
    <div ng-switch on="rows[$index+1].value">
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
            <!-- shows when the value of the next row is true-->
        </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="false">
            <!-- shows when the value of the next row is false-->
        </div>
    </div>   
 </li>
```